# How to pause program execution when pause button is pressed

Tags: iphone

I   want in this action whenever pause button is pressed it should pause the program execution as well because right now when i pause the audio file it still keeps on displaying views one after the other. I want that to be paused as well.

```
 -(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

  if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

 [audioPlayer pause];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[audioPlayer play];

[self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];

  }  

}
```

Anyone know how i can pause the program execution as well.

Comment: What do you mean by _pause the program execution_? Application sends a lot of events to OS all the time, you cann't pause it.

Comment: in my app with i m displaying multiple views when i pause the audiofile, it pauses only audio but views are loading one after the other i want somehow loading of these views should be paused at the same time

Comment: you should paste the code responsible for displaying this views or we can unly guess what's going on there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this   `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];` 
but you will not be able to resume it because your main thread sleeps so you will not receive the touch.

And I also think that your app will not be approved in store.

What I recommend is to use NSTimer to trigger the action and when you press pause just invalidate the timer, when you press play crate a new timer and fire it.